# Why does this Regular Expression match this string?

Tags: regex

I have the string `'05/'`. If I write the pattern `\d+[^\/]{1}`, why does it still match the `'05'` part  of the string? Shouldn't it be fully rejected since there is no match on the 3rd char requirement?

Comment: That is backtracking. Use `\d+\b(?!\/)` or `\d+(?![\/\d])`

Comment: There is no "third char requirement". Your pattern is satisfied with two - `0` for `\d+` repeated exactly once and `5` for `[^\]{1}`. You never mandate *three* characters.

Comment: Thank you both. I now understand why it matched, now trying to wrap my head around the preventable solutions typed and linked.